# Accessing private class member in operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, private

I have an example class which works, [cpp.sh link to the program](http://cpp.sh/5xs6w).

It defines a Complex class with private variables, than it defines the operator overload functions.

```
class Complex
{
private:
  double real, imag ;...
```

But in the overload's implementation, it uses the private variables like they would be public. If it would be a C# program and the `real` and `imag` variables would be properties, It would be okay, but how can a function in `Complex` class can access a `Complex` type parameter's private variables?

```
Complex  Complex::operator+(const Complex &x)
{
  return  Complex(real + x.real, imag + x.imag) ; 
}
```

Comment: Class instances of the same class can access the private members in other instances. It's the scope of the code that ensures that.

Comment: You can't do something like this in Java or C#, can you?

Comment: IIRC it's the same in Java or C#